# Remind me when CPU/Memory/Disk/Network changes in the Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, email, task-manager, reminder, alert

I am running some program which keeps the Disk utilisation at high percentage. When the program finishes, the Disk utilisation drops to low level. Is that possible I can be emailed, or some other alerts, to remind me the ending of this program? e.g. when the Disk utilisation
lower than 20% for 1 min, email me or release a sound.

[image]

Comment: [How to Set Up Monitoring to Alert on Windows High System Usage – CloudSavvy IT](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/3931/how-to-set-up-monitoring-to-alert-on-windows-high-system-usage/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write a powershell script for this:

```
for(){
$params=@{
  ClassName = 'Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk'
  Filter = "Name = '_Total'"
  ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
}
$data=gwmi @params
if($data.splitIOpersec -lt 20){
sleep -s 60
if($data.splitIOpersec -lt 20){
$email=@{
  'From' = 'THE EMAIL ADDRESS OF SENDER COMPUTER'
  'To' = 'THE EMAIL ADDRESS OF YOU'
  'Subject' = 'Disk usage notification'
  'Body' = 'Disk utilisation percentage is lower than 20% for more than 1 minute.'
  'SMTPServer' = 'smtp.gmail.com'
  'Port' = 587
}
$cred=New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential "SENDER EMAIL ID", ("SENDER PASSWORD" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
Send-MailMessage @email -UseSSL -Credential $cred
}}}
```

This uses GMail to send the email with SMTP server smtp.gmail.com and Port 587 with SSL. Replace as your needs.

(*Script will run forever on sender computer unless you terminate with CTRL+C*)

Comment: Thanks, how should I save this script, which file extension? Then how to run it?

Comment: The file extension would be .ps1 and make the necessary changes as highlighted

Comment: So I need to replace 'THE EMAIL ADDRESS OF SENDER COMPUTER', 'THE EMAIL ADDRESS OF YOU', "SENDER EMAIL ID", "SENDER PASSWORD"? Only these four items?  What is "SENDER EMAIL ID"? When running the file.ps1, should I simply type "./file.ps1" at the working directory?

Comment: Yes that's it... set execution policy to RemoteSigned

Comment: How to "set execution policy to RemoteSigned"?

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` from interactive powershell  prompt. To launch powershell prompt run `powershell.exe`.

Comment: And also if you dont use GMail you might need to change SMTP server and port number and change use of SSL. Or for exchange accounts, directly do it.